# Count rows that have the same value in mysql and then show item number

Tags: mysql, count

I have the following data and I was hoping I can group them.

```
|       Label             |     Category        |
|   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|   PC Equipment - Install|     Installation    |
|   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|   Table Setup - Install |     Installation    |
```

I wanted to group the following to this output:

```
| Item #|       Label             |     Category        |
|       |   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|       |   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|   1   |   PC Equipment - Install|     Installation    |
|       |   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|       |   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|   2   |   Table Setup - Install |     Installation    |
```

Would that be possible? 
So far this is what I tried

```
SELECT
    @row_number := CASE WHEN Label LIKE "%Install%" THEN @row_number + 1 
                        ELSE "" 
                   END AS row_number,
    Label       
FROM table1 t,
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE deleted = 0
```

The output i got was

```
| Item #|       Label             |     Category        |
|       |   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|       |   PC Equipment          |     Materials       |
|   1   |   PC Equipment - Install|     Installation    |
|       |   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|       |   Table Setup           |     Materials       |
|   1   |   Table Setup - Install |     Installation    |
```

the second number did not increment.

Comment: im sort of grouping the items that have the same label but not exactly grouping them with group by because it will only show one item and i need it to show all of the items and then hopefully showing the item number will server as like this group number for each set of label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is MySQL.  You just need to do the variable arithmetic correctly:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Label LIKE '%Install%'
             THEN cast(@icnt := @icnt + 1 as char(10))
             ELSE ''
        END) AS row_number,
       Label       
FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @icnt := 0) params
WHERE deleted = 0;
```

The reason your method doesn't work is because you are re-setting the counter variable on each row.  So, it goes from `1` to `""`, and the empty string is treated as 0 -- so the next installation, it is incremented to 1.  And so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working now. It says i cant accept the answer after 3 more minutes but ill make sure to check your answer. thank you again!

Comment: Gordon didnt include this part on the new answer. But you need be carefull with the order of you data because can cause unexpected result. You should add an order by like. `ORDER BY Label,
         CASE WHEN Label LIKE "%Install%" THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END` to make sure the install ins the last one.

Comment: @hocuspocus31 . . . Juan is correct.  You really should have an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(Label LIKE "%Install%", rn, '') AS 'Item #',
       Label, Category
FROM (
  SELECT @row_number := CASE 
                           WHEN Label LIKE "%Install%" THEN @row_number + 1
                           ELSE @row_number
                        END AS rn,
         Label, Category
  FROM table1 AS t
  (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS r
  WHERE deleted = 0
  ORDER BY Label) AS t
```